# Array method versus hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, activesupport

I have an object (returned from and API) that is either a hash or an array of hashes. I want to enclose it in an array if it is not already an array.

I tried to apply `Array` on it, which functions in an expected way with numbers or arrays:

```
Array(1) # => [1]
Array([1, 2]) # => [1, 2]
Array([{a: 1}, {b: 2}]) # => [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

but it fails with hashes:

```
Array({a: 1}) # => [[:a, 1]]
```

which should be `[{:a=>1}]`.

Alternatively, I could add a type check:

```
responses = [responses] if responses.is_a?(Hash)
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: `[responses].flatten`.

Comment: Also `ActiveSupport` introduces [`Array#wrap`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: @mudasobwa Perfect, `Array#wrap` is my choice.

Comment: _"either a hash or an array of hashes"_ – any chance to fix the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveSupport` introduces [`Array#wrap`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) that does exactly what you want:

```
Array.wrap(responses)
```

I personally prefer to never use any Rails helpers for many reasons, so I would stick with `[responses].flatten`, or, even better, with the most explicit version:

```
case responses
when Hash then [responses]
when Array then responses
else raise "shit happened"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As @mudasobwa suggested, `[responses].flatten` is perhaps the cleanest solution:

```
[{a: 1}].flatten           #=> [{:a=>1}]
[[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]].flatten #=> [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

Clearly this inconsistent response format is not a great API design; but that's unfortunately the nature of working with external resources...

If each hash in the above array does represent a unique object, then I would leave that code as-is. However, if you actually have a different hash for each attribute of a single entity (?!), then you could further clean up the API response as follows:

```
[{a: 1}].flatten.reduce(:merge)           #=> {:a=>1}
[[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]].flatten.reduce(:merge) #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to enclose it in an array if it is not already an array.

What about:

```
result = [result] unless result.is_a? Array
```

Alternatively, using [`try_convert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-c-try_convert):

```
result = Array.try_convert(result) || [result]
```